# Can jQuery work for html strings that are not in DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html string that I created with a template.

This string has an html table with a bunch of rows, I'd like to manipulate this string using jquery, for example to add some classes to some rows based on logic, or other manipulation and then have jquery return a string. However, it seems that jQuery only manipulates the DOM. But I don't want to post this string into the DOM yet.

```
var origString = "<table><tr id='bla'>...more html inside here...</tr></table>";
//Something like
var newString = $(htmlString -> '#bla').addClass('blaClass');
// this syntax is obviously wrong, but what I mean is I'm trying 
// to look inside the string not the dom
```

Or maybe it's better to post this string into an invisible div first and then manipulate it with jquery?

Comment: You can do it but I forgot the syntax, I am sure someone will post an answer. Got it, $(origString).find(....)

Comment: Can't you just do `$(htmlString).find("tr").addClass("someClass"):`

Comment: What's the concept behind `$(htmlString -> '#bla')`?

Comment: `$(htmlString)` won't insert anything into the DOM and allows manipulation...

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2 -- but note that your HTML must be a complete DOM node or nodes; you can't manipulate `<table><tr><td>` without `</td></tr></table>` being assumed at the end.

Comment: Check out this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/cYBfU/ and my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers were too complicated. The answer is just a dollar sign and some parentheses:

```
var queryObj = $(str);
```

So

```
 var str = "<table><tr>...</tr></table>"
 var queryObj = $(str);
 queryObj.find('tr').addClass('yoyo!'); 
 // if you use 'find' make sure your original html string is a container 
 // in this case it was a 'table' container
 $("body").append(queryObj);
```

works just fine..

Answer (score 5):

Parse it to a variable, manipulate, then append:

```
var origString = "<table><tr id='bla'>...";
origString = $.parseHTML(origString);
$(origString).find("tr").addClass("test");
$("body").append(origString);
```

Concept demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6bkUv/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can definitely manipulate a string with jQuery. Here is what the following code does:

1. Declares a div to wrap the string in
2. Wraps the string in the div and does the manipulation
3. Finally, produces the manipulated string

**No interaction with the DOM whatsoever.**

```
var htmlString = "<table><tr id='bla'>...";
var div = $('<div/>');
div.html( htmlString ).find( '#bla' ).addClass( 'class' );
var newString = div.html();
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/cYBfU/)

```
//OUTPUT
Original:  <table><tr id='bla'><td></td></tr></table>
New:  <table><tbody><tr id="bla" class="class"><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

**NOTE:** Please note that if your table string does not have a `tbody` element jQuery will include it as that makes for valid `table` markup.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can add a class without appending it to the dom.

```
  var origString = "<table><tr id='bla'>...more html inside here...</tr></table>",
  newString = $('<div>'+origString+'</div');
  newString.find('#bla').addClass('blaClass');
  console.log(newString.html());
```